# How can I share a constant in XML resource file and in source code as a static value

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I need the same constant in several places:

- in the Android `strings.xml` XML resource file
- in Kotlin source code as a static string (**without access to a context**)

How can I do?

I can see 3 possibilities, possible or not, but I don't see how to implement any of them:

**a) Define the constant as resource in `strings.xml`, and import it in the source code.**

XML: OK

```xml
<string name="my_constant">My.value</string>
```

Problem: I cannot define it as static / constant in my code, since I need a context to get its value, for ex. with `context.getString(R.string.my_constant)`. Unless there is another way to do so, but I haven't found it.

Kotlin: ?

```kotlin
    companion object {
        const val MY_CONSTANT = ??.getString(R.string.my_constant)
    }
```

**b) Define the consant in the Kotlin source code, and import its value in the XML resource file.**

Kotlin: OK

```kotlin
    companion object {
        const val MY_CONSTANT = "My.value"
    }
```

Problem: I haven't found a way to import the value in `strings.xml`.

XML:?

```xml
<string name="my_constant" value="???"/>
```

**c) Define the constant in `build.gradle`, import the value in both XML and Kotlin source code.**

Problem: I just don't know how to do it, I've tried with `BuildConfig` but couldn't get the value in the source code.

gradle: ?

```
    buildTypes {
        all {
            // does not seem correct:
            buildConfigField 'String', 'MY_CONSTANT', '"My.value"'
        }
        release {
           // ... other settings
        }
    }
```

XML: ?
Kotlin: ?

```kotlin
    companion object {
        const val MY_CONSTANT = BuildConfig.MY_CONSTANT // does not work
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually define my API constants like this

define your constant in gradle.properties

```
API_KEY=""
```

then in your build.gradle(Module)

```
defaultConfig {

buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", API_KEY)

}
```

now you should be able to call the constant from anywhere

```
BuildConfig.API_KEY
```

Comment: That's the c) I had tried, and I've tried again but BuildConfig does not have the field after rebuilding with Gradle. It's an Android application in Kotlin, and I'm adding the `buildConfigField` as you show in the `defaultConfig` part that is already in the `build.gradle` of the module (with `minSdkVersion` and so on).

Comment: I'm starting to wonder whether `BuildConfig` may be masked by another class of the same name. I see that IntelliJ imports it as `androidx.viewbinding.BuildConfig`.

Comment: It turns out IntelliJ must not import it, so the import should be turned down and IntelliJ marks it as an error, yet it compiles just fine. Yet another problem with this IDE. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: It does not compile with Boolean type though, not with Kotlin. Just something more to add to the stack of current issues.

Comment: Found out why, you have to use native Java types for `int` and `boolean`, or it won't be considered as constant for some obscure reason. And it's OK to use that in `buildConfigField`.

Comment: Good to know for future endeavors, I haven't used it for things other than my API keys but I'm sure it will be useful at some point.